# Gradlew build fail

Tags: java, linux, archlinux, gradlew, minecraft-forge

When i'm trying to run `./gradlew build` i get an error `BUILD FAILED in {Time}`.If you see the logs below you knew that i'm trying install a minecraft mod to all versions with JVM option.

- Operation System(OS): Arch linux
- Java version: Java 8 Runtime Environment(JRE8) + Java 8 Development Kit(JDK8)
- Error logs: https://hastebin.com/ejubujavin.sql
- Gradle build file: https://hastebin.com/fixegiyogo.cs

Comment: post the gradle build file.

Comment: I don't know where is it i searched all gradle files and git project's build file

Comment: Please post the actual error text, not a picture.

Comment: there should be a build file somewhere. usually called build.gradle in the same directory that you did the: ". ./gradlew build" in.

Answer (score 0):

> but if there are any issues, run ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace before
>   ./gradlew build.

It was stated clearly in the build guide, ForgeGradle 2.8 doesn't work without running setup first.